# Filler working inconsistently

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I can't get the Filler to work consistently.

Here's the setup I've used (successfully) before:

- Redstone torch next to
- Stirling engine (powered with lava) next to
- Filler with 3x3 Glass to clear the area
- Landmarks set correctly with perimeter highlighting in red

Problems I'm having:

- Lights on the top of the Filler are red, not green, and nothing's happening
- Red perimeter made by Landmarks only turns black and yellow sometimes (can't figure out a pattern here)

The Filler worked in this area for a while and then just stopped. I'm at Y65 so bedrock should not be an issue. I picked up the Filler and all my Landmarks and reset them but with no success.

Comment: what do you mean by filler with 9x9 glass? do you mean 3x3 so its in the clear state? Also a Stirling engine isn't near enough power to use a filler sufficiently. Also, are you successfully making the landmark grid by right clicking the main corner, and then attaching the filler to that corner? There's a lot of things that could go wrong here so I am waiting to pinpoint what is in order to answer.

Comment: and the area must be set before the filler is put down

Comment: I can't figure out what your setup is by this description, please include a screenshot(s)?

Comment: @Rapitor you're right, I meant 3x3. I've changed my note above. And a Stirling Engine will work (another of mine is working right now). I'm sure it's not optimal, but for the time being, I don't want to mess with it. Yes, I am making the landmark grid by right-clicking the main corner, which turns the perimeter red, and then placing the filler adjacent to that main corner landmark.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thanks for asking; I am laying down the area first.

Comment: @Ender Here's a [screenshot of my setup](http://cl.ly/UCCB). There is no lava in the engine now, but I put some in and it turns blue and pumps with no problems. This gets my other fillers working. I know it's not the best solution, but I want to fix only one problem at a time.

Comment: Update on the problem: when the black and yellow tape appears, sometimes when I set the filler, the lights will flash green for a second and then immediately revert to red.

Comment: can you get a screenshot of the area of the grid?

Comment: @Rapitor I've given up on that area and moved elsewhere. Think something inside of my grid could be causing the problem? There was some lava in there. But the fact that the lasers turned to black and yellow tape makes me think it was working well.

Comment: @JackBrannen it's possible the area you wanted to work with was too large. I don't know if fillers have troubles with liquids, I didn't think they did, but that also might be a possibility.

Comment: @Rapitor Liquids: duly noted. That might be the culprit. The area I landmarked was within the blue laser limits of the original landmark, so I'd be surprised if size were the problem. Then again, who knows.

Comment: @Rapitor I've learned for certain that if a mob is in the open space where a Filler is trying to lay down a block, the Filler will wait and maybe stop.